# How to use imported packages (JsonRpc)

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, package, laravel-5

I am trying to use the **JsonRpc** package in **Laravel 5.0** in order to access Bitcoin RPC commands. So far, I have successfully install the dev-master branch of JsonRpc through composer; generated autoload files and have managed to view the jsonrpc folder under the vendor folder.

So, I am now trying to access the package from a controller named '*PoolController.php*'. This is the code I am trying to use to achieve this:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use vendor\JsonRpc\JsonRpc\src\JsonRpc\client;

class PoolController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $bitcoind = JsonRpc::jsonRPCClient('http://username:password@localhost:8332/');
        $balance = $bitcoind->getbalance("");
        return view('pool');
    }

}
```

To verify, I am trying to access the '*jsonRPCClient*' function located inside of Client.php. The location and structure of the file is as follows:

```
project-root\vendor\jsonrpc\jsonrpc\src\JsonRpc\Base\Client.php
```

However, this does not seem to be the way to access imported modules in Laravel 5, instead Laravel is trying to find a controller named 'JsonRpc' and in doing so is throwing this exception saying that the controller could not be found:

```
FatalErrorException in PoolController.php line 9:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\JsonRpc' not found
```

So, my question is, how would one go around using an external composer-installed package in Laravel 5.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PSR autoloading you don't need to include the entire vendor directory path as part of the namespace. If you look into the `vendor\jsonrpc\jsonrpc\src\JsonRpc\Base\Client.php` file you'll see the namespace declaration at the begining of the file is `namespace JsonRpc;`. So all you need to use is that namespace and the class name:

```
use JsonRpc\Client;
```

And instantiate the class like this:

```
$bitcoind = Client('http://username:password@localhost:8332/');
```

Or just instantiate it using the full class namespace (this means there's no need for the `use` statement):

```php
$bitcoind = \JsonRpc\Client('http://username:password@localhost:8332/');
```

You can read more on how namespaces work in the [PHP Namespaces Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php).

Answer (score 0):

In your code , the `JsonRpc` under the current namespace (App\Http\Controllers), so `'App\Http\Controllers\JsonRpc' not found`.

Importe the package like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use JsonRpc\Client as JsonRpcClient;

class PoolController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $client = new JsonRpcClient($url);
        $client->call('method', array($param1, $param2));
        # your code
    }

}
```